# Share image and text to Twitter Feed

Tags: android, twitter

I wanted to share image and text to twitter Feed from my android app. I have tried many methods to share image on twitter feed but it is not working for me. I am able to share text but not image. Can someone suggest me how can i share the image on Twitter from my android app.
I am trying to share the image through following code:-

```
        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
                .text("Any text here.")//any sharing text here
                .image(imageUri);//sharing image uri
        builder.show();
```

Comment: You should add, which methods you have tried and what challenge did you face.

Answer (score 0):

use this function for sharing text and to twitter

```
public void shareTwitter()
    {
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis;
            fis = getActivity().openFileInput("photo.jpg");
            Bitmap shot = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            File file = new File(MapView.path, "snapshot.jpg");
            if(file.exists()){
                Log.i("FILE", "YES");
            }else{
                Log.i("FILE", "NO");
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

            Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "Insert Tweet Here";
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
            //in catch block will be called
            waIntent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share to twitter);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser"Share with"));

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return ;
        }
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: I tried above but it gives You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device... but i have already installed the app

Comment: try my updated answer seems like twitter changed packaged structure @Dhanveerthakur